# Activity Transition animation in a ListView in Android Lollipop with Material Design

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, activity-transition

I am using a Master/Detail pattern and currently moving to Android Lollipop. I want to have one of the [new activity transistions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) if I click on a item in my ListView. The animations are working but I do not know how to make a certain animation between the shared element (in my case a ImageView).

If I click on a row in my custom ListView (with image and text), the transition should switch to the image in my DetailActivtiy. It should look like in this video: http://youtu.be/RhiPJByIMrM?t=2m41s or this video: http://youtu.be/XkWI1FKKrs4

I already added this code to both of my ImageViews:

```
<ImageView
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_title_image"/>
```

My ListActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        //To enable window content transitions in your code instead, call the Window.requestFeature() method:
        getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Transition ts_enter = new Slide();  //Slide(); //Explode();
        Transition ts_exit = new Explode();

        ts_enter.setDuration(2000);
        ts_exit.setDuration(2000);
        /*
        If you have set an enter transition for the second activity,
        the transition is also activated when the activity starts.
        */
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts_enter);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(ts_exit);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Using this method to call my DetailActivity:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleListActivity.this, ArticleDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("pos", id);
        intent.putExtra("articleList", articleList);
        String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_title_image);
        ImageView article_thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.article_thumb);

        ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ArticleListActivity.this,
                        article_thumb,   // The view which starts the transition
                        transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
                );
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(ArticleListActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
    }
```

My DetailActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        //To enable window content transitions in your code instead, call the Window.requestFeature() method:
        getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Transition ts_enter = new Slide();  //Slide(); //Explode();
        Transition ts_exit = new Explode();  //Slide(); //Explode();

        ts_enter.setDuration(2000);
        ts_exit.setDuration(2000);

        getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts_enter);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(ts_exit);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

;

Comment: OK, but you didn't explain what the problem is. What does the animation look like right now? Does a glitch occur? In your code you have set content transitions using `setEnterTransition()` and `setExitTransition()`, but where do you set the shared element transitions?

Comment: Also, you might want to consider posting a video of your own application if you are having trouble describing the problem you are seeing. Android Studio has a very useful video capture tool that might come in handy.

Comment: [**This blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. First, make sure you give each `ImageView` in your first activity a unique transition name. If all of the image views have the same transition name, the framework will not know which one to choose when the animation begins and the transition will not behave properly.
2. When the `ImageView` is clicked, pass its unique transition name to the details activity as an `Intent` extra.
3. In the details activity's `onCreate()` method, retrieve the name from the intent bundle, and set it as the `ImageView`'s transition name.

Comment: Just a tweak: you should not use the unique transition name in the intent extra. You should use the transition name used in the details Activity. The unique name is automatically associated so that when you come back, the framework knows which View to associate with the shared element, even if the Activity is recreated. ApiDemos has a simple example that should help.

Comment: @GeorgeMount I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean. By "ApiDemos", do you mean this sample project? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic

Comment: @GeorgeMount I found the ApiDemos [**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/). However, I am still confused why it is necessary to map the shared element using a `SharedElementCallback` in this situation... what would be wrong with passing the shared element to the called activity inside an `Intent` instead? Do you mean that there is there a possibility that some sort of state-loss related bug could occur if one of the activities got destroyed and recreated by the system? Am I missing something?

Comment: When you go from a detail Activity to a list Activity, the framework has to know which View in the list Activity to have as the shared element. When you are going "back" it can figure it out for you because you used it going forward. When going forward, you may know the specific transitionName in the list Activity, but more likely, you are sharing a more generic name and it is up to the list Activity to assign the right view. If you aren't in the same app, for example, you don't have insight into the remote app's naming scheme (other than agreed-upon the shared element name).

Comment: Ahh, OK... that is a good point about activities that live in separate applications. Thanks for clearing that up!